# Time based accumulation based on type: Speed considerations in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

Based on surfing the web, I came up with two methods of counting the records in a table "Table1".  The counter field increments according to a date field "TheDate".  It does this by summing records with an older TheDate value.  Furthermore, records with different values for the compound field (Field1,Field2) are counted using separate counters.  Field3 is just an informational field that is included for added awareness and does not affect the counting or how records are grouped for counting.

**Method 1: Use corrrelated subquery**

```
SELECT MainQuery.Field1,
       MainQuery.Field2,
       MainQuery.Field3,
       MainQuery.TheDate,
   (
      SELECT SUM(1) FROM Table1 InnerQuery
      WHERE InnerQuery.Field1   = MainQuery.Field1 AND
            InnerQuery.Field2   = MainQuery.Field2 AND
            InnerQuery.TheDate <= MainQuery.TheDate
   ) AS RunningCounter
FROM Table1 MainQuery
ORDER BY MainQuery.Field1,
         MainQuery.Field2,
         MainQuery.TheDate,
         MainQuery.Field3
```

**Method 2: Use join and group-by**

```
SELECT MainQuery.Field1,
       MainQuery.Field2,
       MainQuery.Field3,
       MainQuery.TheDate,
       SUM(1) AS RunningCounter
FROM Table1 MainQuery INNER JOIN Table1 InnerQuery
ON InnerQuery.Field1   = MainQuery.Field1 AND
   InnerQuery.Field2   = MainQuery.Field2 AND
   InnerQuery.TheDate <= MainQuery.TheDate
GROUP BY MainQuery.Field1,
         MainQuery.Field2,
         MainQuery.Field3,
         MainQuery.TheDate
ORDER BY MainQuery.Field1,
         MainQuery.Field2,
         MainQuery.TheDate,
         MainQuery.Field3
```

There is no inner query per se in Method 2, but I use the table alias InnerQuery so that a ready parellel with Method 1 can be drawn.  The role is the same; the 2nd instance of Table 1 is for accumulating the counts of the records which have TheDate less than that of any record in MainQuery (1st instance of Table 1) with the same Field1 and Field2 values.

Note that in Method 2, Field 3 is include in the Group-By clause even though I said that it does not affect how the records are grouped for counting.  This is still true, since the counting is done using the matching records in InnerQuery, whereas the GROUP By applies to Field 3 in MainQuery.

I found that Method 1 is noticably faster.  I'm surprised by this because it uses a correlated subquery.  The way I think of a correlated subquery is that it is executed for each record in MainQuery (whether or not that is done in practice after optimization).  On the other hand, Method 2 doesn't run an inner query over and over again.  However, the inner join still has multiple records in InnerQuery matching each record in MainQuery, so in a sense, it deals with a similar order of complexity.

Is there a decent intuitive explanation for this speed difference, as well as best practice or considerations in choosing an approach for time-base accumulation?

I've posted this to

- [Microsoft Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-access/time-based-accumulation-based-on-type-speed/0fb75d5f-84ef-4477-b59d-a8448377b4f4?tm=1439308664011)
- [Stack Exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31946634/time-based-accumulation-based-on-type-speed-considerations-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I think the easiest way is to do this:

```
SELECT MainQuery.Field1,
       MainQuery.Field2,
       MainQuery.Field3,
       MainQuery.TheDate,
       COUNT(*)
FROM Table1 MainQuery
GROUP BY MainQuery.Field1,
         MainQuery.Field2,
         MainQuery.Field3,
         MainQuery.TheDate
ORDER BY MainQuery.Field1,
         MainQuery.Field2,
         MainQuery.TheDate,
         MainQuery.Field3
```

(The order by isn't required to get the same data, just to order it. In other words, removing it will not change the number or contents of each row returned, just the order in which they are returned.)

You only need to specify the table once. Doing a self-join (joining a table to itself as both your queries do) is not required. The performance of your two queries will depend on a whole load of things which I don't know - what the primary keys are, the number of rows, how much memory is available, and so on.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need a running total with time, which will be processed later.  A simple count(*) does not fulfill the need.

Comment: Though it does make sense to use COUNT(*) in the inner query instead of using SUM(1).  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, your experience makes a lot of sense. I'm not sure why you need *more* intuition.  I imagine you learned, somewhere along the way, that correlated subqueries are evil.  Well, as with some of the things we teach kids as being really bad ("don't cross the street when the walk sign is not green") turn out to be not so bad, the same is true of correlated subqueries.

The easiest intuition is that the uncorrelated subquery has to aggregate all the data in the table.  The correlated version only has to aggregate matching fields, although it has to do this over and over.

To put numbers to it, say you have 1,000 rows with 10 rows per group.  The output is 100 rows.  The first version does 100 aggregations of 10 rows each.  The second does one aggregation of 1,000 rows.  Well, aggregation generally scales in a super-linear fashion (O(n log n), technically).  That means that 100 aggregations of 10 records takes less time than 1 aggregation of 1000 records.

You asked for intuition, so the above is to provide some intuition.  There are a zillion caveats that go both ways.  For instance, the correlated subquery might be able to make better use of indexes for the aggregation.  And, the two queries are not equivalent, because the correct join would be `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong.  The inner join is way, way faster than the correlated subquery.  However, the correlated subquery is able to display its results records as they are generated, so it appears faster.  I'm going to post this as an answer in addition to a follow-up to your comment.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: BTW, I never learned that correlated subqueries were evil...in fact, I wasn't even sure if the compiler had sneaky ways to get around the perception that it has to be executed for each record in the main query.  I guess now I know!

Comment: @user36800 . . . Do you have an index on `(field1, field2, thedate)`?

Comment: No, it's pretty fast without it.  I use to index everything that I thought I would serve as a fast lookup, but then started getting error messages and these days, I just don't.  Bad, I know, but I was never able to figure out the error messages.  It was months back.  I may revisit that at some point.  Why, would indexing somehow make up for the correlated subquery penalty?

Comment: @user36800 . . . Because the index can be used for the correlation piece, accessing only the rows that match the `where` conditions.

Comment: OK, thanks.  Something to experiment with at some point.  I'll have to revisit the errors I got in the past from indexing.  Get that sorted out first.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was wrong in my original post.  The inner join is way, way faster than the correlated subquery.  However, the correlated subquery is able to display its results records as they are generated, so it appears faster.

As a side curiosity, I'm finding that if the correlated sub-query approach is modified to use sum(-1) instead of sum(1), the number of returned records seems to vary from N-3 to N (where N is the correct number, i.e., the number of records in Table1).  I'm not sure if this is due to some misbehaviour in Access's rush to display initial records or what-not.

While it seems that the INNER JOIN wins hands-down, there is a major insidious caveat.  If the GROUP BY fields do not uniquely distinguish each record in Table1, then you will not get an individual SUM for each record of Table1.  Imagine that a particular combination of GROUP BY field values matching (say) THREE records in Table1.  You will then get a single SUM for *all* of them.  The problem is, *each* of these 3 records in MainQuery also matches *all* 3 of the same records in InnerQuery, so those instances in InnerQuery get counted multiple times.  *Very* insidious (I find).

So it seems that the sub-query may be the way to go, which is awfully disturbing in view of the above problem with repeatability (2nd paragraph above).  That is a serious problem that should send shivers down any spine.  Another possible solution that I'm looking at is to turn MainQuery into a subquery by SELECTing the fields of interest and DISTINCTifying them before INNER JOINing the result with InnerQuery.

Comment: Just to close the loose end on this answer, the closing sentence above worked perfectly.